# Connecting First Passage Time to Power Spectrum

Tags: fourier-analysis, roots

Let $f$ be a real function. Is there a connection between

- The first positive abscissa for which its autocorrelation function is equal to zero (which I call the first passage time, fpt)
- The largest frequency of $f$'s power spectrum

For the matter, we can assume $f$ infinitely differentiable, square-integrable and anything more if needed. I know the Wiener-Khinchin theorem relates autocorrelation to power spectrum, but I'm not sure how to go further.

Comment: wait you ask $f$ a Schwartz function ? then ... no the first zero-crossing are not related to the spectrum, but a relevant example might be boring to find. Do you have a practical problem in mind ?

Comment: Not really. In my case $f$ is a cubic spline, and I want to quantify its wigglyness. The fpt is one way to do that

Comment: Never heard about the wigglyness. Can you elaborate ? (I know a lot on signal processing)

Comment: By wigglyness I meant a characteristic lengthscale, what in physics we call correlation length or persistence length https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_function_%28statistical_mechanics%29

Comment: You should explain your precise problem (with your cubic splines), because until now I don't understand it